# reCaptcha giving an error with no description

Tags: php, recaptcha

Alright so I'm trying to get captcha to work here and I have this little error detecting thing that looks like this. I'm not going to paste the entire page as that would be way too long, only the essentials

page1

```
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/recaptchalib.php');
  echo recaptcha_get_html($reCaptcha_publickey); ?>
    <?php  echo $_SESSION['devtest'];?>
```

page2

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) 
{
    $_SESSION['devtest'] = $resp->error . "testzzz"; // DEVELOPING, DELETE THIS
    $errors = $errors . "'1',";
    // Returns errors to page1
}
```

Now the $errors does have the '1', in it, it echoes the "testzzz" part of devtest fine but it displays no error.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: I followed this guide for the most part, i only changed the code for the if statement https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Comment: var_dump($resp) and see if the error variable is even being populated

Comment: page2 now gives the error "NULL
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/path/upload2.php:38) in /home/path/upload2.php on line 52" No clue what that could possibly mean

Comment: Oh i see, when i remove a header() function below, it just gives NULL, so there's my problem.. still don't know how to solve it though, it dooes include the recaptchalib file through require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/recaptchalib.php'); so it sounds like it should work fine

Comment: hmmm.  well, if your code is echoing out an error somewhere before session is declared that could be causing it.  You can probably find the cause of the header problem by checking the network tab in chrome.   if youre using the google recaptcha youre likely using some kind of ajax so see if theres an error in your ajax thats not rendering to the page via the network tab in chrome or the console in firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resp->error` is what you're looking for, `$resp->is_valid` is a Boolean value, and I think it's deprecated since reCaptcha became part of googles main tools so you might be checking a variable that doesn't exits. so `(!$resp->is_valid)`  always returns TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself... i don't know why the default google code didnt work but simply

replacing

if (!$resp->is_valid)

with

if ($resp->error)

and it works for some reason

Comment: You know, @Neo solved this and gave you a reason. Adding the answer that he gave yourself and accepting yours seems unfair to Neo. (Also, use four spaces before code to turn on highlighting)

Comment: Yeah except that I answered this myself a few days before he answered anything.. I didn't even get a chance to change the solution to his answer yet